# Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC'. Expecting CONVERSATION

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

The first part of code is working perfectly but the second part doesn't work at all and shows

> Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC'.  Expecting CONVERSATION.

I tried to use select instead for set and also tried to use conversion function but this fails

---

```
    if (@totalCash is null)
        BEGIN
          select @totalCash = 0
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
          set @totalCash = @totalCash
        END
    END




    declare @execute as int
    --قائمه التتدفقات النقديه 
    EXEC @execute = CashFlowInsert 'التدفقات النقديه من أنشطه التشغيل' ,' ' 
    -- التدفقات النقديه من أنشطه التشغيل
    --عجز  (فائض  ) إيرادات العام  

   -- > first Part
    declare @TotRevnu  as int
    declare @TotExpens  as int
    declare @totalCash as int
     --select @TotRevnu  =  sum(CASE WHEN total is null then 0 else total end) AS tot1 from RevnuView
    SET @TotRevnu  =  (select sum(CASE WHEN total is null then 0 else total end) AS tot1 from RevnuView)
    set @TotExpens  = (select sum(case when total is null then 0 else total END)as tot2 from expensessview)

    Set @totalCash  =  @TotRevnu  - @TotExpens  
    if (@totalCash is null)
        BEGIN
          set  @totalCash = 0
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
          set  @totalCash = @totalCash
        END
    END
    EXEC @execute = CashFlowInsert ' عجز (فائض ) الايراد العام ' , @totalCash 
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    EXEC @execute = CashFlowInsert ' يتم تسويته بـ : ' ,' ' 
    -- المخصصات احمالى 

 --- > Second Part 
    declare @TotAllowances as int
    set  @TotAllowances = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (temp_budget.Debit - temp_budget.Credit) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (temp_budget.Debit - temp_budget.Credit) END) AS total
                          FROM     temp_budget INNER JOIN  asset_ss ON temp_budget.Code = asset_ss.code WHERE  (temp_budget.Code LIKE '24%'))
    if (@TotAllowances is null)
        BEGIN
             set   @TotAllowances = 0
        END
    else
        BEGIN 
             set @TotAllwances  =  @TotAllowances   
        end 
    END


    EXEC @execute = CashFlowInsert 'مخصص مكون خلال العام ' , @TotAllowances
```

---

CashFlowInsert    Code

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[CashFlowInsert] (   
    @param1 as nvarchar(255) ,      
    @param2 as int) 
As   
begin     
    insert into CashFlowReport(CData,CtotalNew) values (@param1, @param2 )  
end
```

Comment: Post the code for `CashFlowInsert`

Comment: Please stop bouncing the accepted answer between the answers you've got. This is only causing confusion. If neither of the current answers solves the problem, do not mark any of them as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure since it seems like you've only shown a partial code, but maybe this is your problem?

```
if (@totalCash is null)
    BEGIN
      set  @totalCash = 0
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
      set  @totalCash = @totalCash
    END
END -- This `END` have no corresponding `BEGIN`
```

and in any case, this condition can be simplified to

```
SET @totalCash = ISNULL(@totalCash, 0)
```

Comment: if confused when I use the end word in the first if it works great but when I use it in another one it conflicts and I had to remove the end word  ... I used the construction of if statement as   if (condition) begin result end end